# Web clients needs to interact with a private server database

Tags: .net, sql-server, web-services, wcf

We have an SQL server 2005 installed on a server in a network inside the business building. Currently the server cannot be accessed over the web and we would like to keep it so.

Now we have a website where clients can fill out bookings and perform payments. To do so we need to connect and get data from the database. We are thinking of using web services (WCF) however we're not going to host the service on our local server, instead it is going to be hosted on a 3rd party hosting provider.

This is where we have an issue. The integration with the wcf and website are not a problem as it is just a standard service, but is there a way to create a service in this scenario?

Web client------Connects to------>WCF Service

WCF Service------Sends request to------>Local Server

Local Server------Sends data to------>WCF Service

WCF------>Sends data to------> Web client

Through our research we found out about duplex communication and callback contracts but we're unsure if it can apply to us. From what we can figure out, we need to have the local server to listen to the WCF and act accordingly when a request comes in.

Please help us figure out if we're going in the complete wrong direction or if we should go on this path. Also is there any better standardized way of performing there kind of operations?

Comment: Are you saying you need to host a website on the cloud, but that website needs data from an on-premise database?

Comment: And are you also saying that your are currently thinking about how a WCF service can help in this scenario? If so then would the WCF service be also hosted on the cloud, or could you put it on-premise?

Comment: Its on the cloud, however, we're considering to host it ourselves as this is all contradictory in itself. With the WCF, we were hoping to achive something like a duplex connection between the WCF and SQL and each client request is redirectedto the SQL server and back again to the client through the publisher/subscriber architecture, though it sounds so much simpler in words, than in actual reality

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would allow your local database to accept connections from the server which will host your WCF service. You can set it up so only that server can connect to your database and therefore although it's accessible by the web it only accepts your WCF host.

However, it may be easier if you just have stored procedures and a basic API. Not sure what your website is made of, whether it's ASP.net or PHP or something else but I am currently working on a system which like yourselves has a MSSQL DB on client's own private network. We did this way:

PHP application has interfaces to get data from the MSSQL server (it gets data directly from the tables to preserve integrity). Then we have a purpose to send data to their database but that data needs to trigger other things on the client's end so we created a stored procedure on the MSSQL server to handle the data manipulation when it arrives. The data is identified by GUID.

On the web application (PHP) we have interfaces to be able to change this implementation in the future as it may become required. I'm also using a queue service so that if the connection gets lost then the data is queued for later but I also have several checks to ensure no duplication and overwriting etc.

Also, I am caching the records from the MSSQL Database so that the data gets refreshed in a queue and thus it doesn't affect the users' performance.

Let me know if you need further clarification - we have the exact same names :)

Comment: Small world indeed :)

Yes, that would be ideal to open the server up for the WCF service as it would automatically fix this problem. The API is hosted on the local client's server?